# firebase realtime database, how to read only own data?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a realtime database in my nextjs webapp and I use it for notifications.

The schema of my db is the following:

[image]

I write data only from server side as admin, but read it from clientside in the following way:

```
  const fetchNotifications = () => {
    const starCountRef = ref(db, `notifications/${user?.id}`);
    const q = query(starCountRef, orderByChild('createdAt'), limitToLast(100));
    onValue(q, (snapshot) => {
      //Handle data
    });
  };
```

In this moment I have the following rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": false,
    "notifications":{
      "$user_id":{".indexOn":"createdAt"}
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see everyone that is authenticated can read everything. I want the user to read only his own notifications. The ObjectID is a reference from my mongoDB.

For example if I have `ID = 1` I want to access data only for path `/notifications/1` and if I try to get data from `/notifications/2` then I get nothing (or error).

First of all how can I see from firebase the ID I use in my local DB? Have I to let him know first? Second how can I write it in my rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the keys directly under `notifications` are the Firebase Authentication UIDs (as your rules suggest), you can limit access to only the user's node with:

```
{
  "rules": {
    //".read": "auth != null", //  Remove this line
    ".write": false,
    "notifications":{
      "$user_id":{
        ".read": "auth.uid === $user_id", //  add this line
        ".indexOn":"createdAt"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [securing content-owner only access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#realtime-database_2).

Comment: Keys under /notifications actually are not the firebase auth UIDs, but the user's id in my local DB.. I think must use the firebase uid, isn't it?

Comment: You don't have to, but you'll need to have the UID that can have access in the data that they're trying to access somewhere. If the key *isn't* a UID, then what *is*?

Comment: That key is an ObjectID stored in my local mongoDB. When I write a notification I get the path `/notifications/${userMongoDbID}` and I push there the new notification. In order to make the users read only their notifications I should write to `/notifications/${firebaseUID}`  isn't it? If I don't it is all right, it works, but if someone malicious wants to read the other user's data they potentially can do it.

Comment: You seem to know how to solve that security hole though, so 